# AuthorizeView blazor webassembly doesn't work

Tags: .net, razor, blazor, identity

I'm using Identity in Blazor app. I sed table AspNetRoles with my 3 roles: "user" "administrator" "moderator". And on succesfully registration there is creating relation in AspNetUserRoles between role and user. All works to this moment, but when Im trying to check role with

```
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "user")]
```

or

```
<AuthorizeView Roles="user">...
```

It doesn't see roles and I always get NotAuthorized view. Should I add this roles in any way in Startup.cs or sth?
Here is my startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddSingleton<TableManager>();
/*            services.AddSingleton<ScoreManager>();*/

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("user", policy => policy.RequireRole("user"));
            });

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddTransient<RolesSeeder>();
        }
```

Policy doesnt work too, when I use @attribute[Authorize(Policy="user")]
or same wwith  I'm getting error "An unhandled error has occurred. Reload".

Edit 1:
Roles seeder:

```
 public class RolesSeeder
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext dbContext;

        public RolesSeeder(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
        }
        public async void SeedRoles()
        {
            var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(dbContext);

            if(!(dbContext.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "administrator")))
            {
                await roleStore.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole { Name = "administrator", NormalizedName = "administrator" });
            }
            if (!(dbContext.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "user")))
            {
                await roleStore.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole { Name = "user", NormalizedName = "user" });
            }
            if (!(dbContext.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "moderator")))
            {
                await roleStore.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole { Name = "moderator", NormalizedName = "moderator" });
            }

            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

Added in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddTransient<RolesSeeder>();
```

Register.cshtml added:

```
                    if (user.UserName.Contains("admin"))
                    {
                        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "administrator");
                    }
                    if (user.UserName.Contains("moderator"))
                    {
                        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "moderator");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "user");
                    }
```

Comment: How are you "Seeding" the  roles? What claims are being attached if any? If there is a role claim is it multiple roles in one claim? Is the `@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "user")]` is being applied to a page NOT a component?

Comment: It seems like you are attaching the roles after login? The claims will not be included in the current session.

Comment: Hi, I added in edit what I did for make roles. I havent done anything else so if I forgot something would be good to now. At this moment @attribute [Authorize(Roles = "user")] works only for user role. If user has another role, for example "administrator" and I authorize page for administrator role it doesn;t authorize this user.

Comment: This is a known behaviour. If the user has multiple roles in one claim you have to transform them into multiple single claims. Ill try find a link I have answered this before.

Comment: I do only one record in AspNetUserRoles for single user, so user has only one role if you mean it.

Answer (score 1):

In the client add:

```
builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization().AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomUserFactory>();
```

```
public class CustomUserFactory : AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteUserAccount>
{
    public CustomUserFactory(IAccessTokenProviderAccessor accessor)
           : base(accessor)
    {
    }
    public override async ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserAsync(
        RemoteUserAccount account,
        RemoteAuthenticationUserOptions options)
    {
        var user = await base.CreateUserAsync(account, options);
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity;
        if (account is not null) {
            MapArrayClaimsToMultipleSeparateClaims(account, claimsIdentity);
        }
        return user;
    }
    private void MapArrayClaimsToMultipleSeparateClaims(RemoteUserAccount account, ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity)
    {
        foreach (var keyValuePair in account.AdditionalProperties) {
            var key = keyValuePair.Key;
            var value = keyValuePair.Value;
            if (value is not null &&
                value is JsonElement element && element.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Array) {
                claimsIdentity.RemoveClaim(claimsIdentity.FindFirst(keyValuePair.Key));
                var claims = element.EnumerateArray()
                    .Select(x => new Claim(keyValuePair.Key, x.ToString()));
                claimsIdentity.AddClaims(claims);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If your seeding roles after login. The relevant user needs to logout then in again to have the claims.

Comment: I needed to add the following line in my AddMsalAuthentication in program.cs to get this to work: options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "roles";